# RewriteRule returns empty GET … while others work …

Tags: .htaccess

Why doesn’t this work?

```
RewriteRule ^search/(\w+)$ index.php?ecSTAGE=query&query=$1

RewriteRule ^search(\w+)$ index.php?ecSTAGE=query&query=$1
```

The given URL is `example.com/index.php?ecSTAGE=query&query=blah`  and should be `example.com/search?q=blah` .

Well … the latter (yes, the latter) is what I want to get …

So … this may be too elaborated …

```
RewriteRule search$ index.php?ecSTAGE=query
```

works fine but the GET-Parameters are empty …

Then

```
RewriteRule search$ index.php?ecSTAGE=query&query=$1
```

should work … shouldn’t it? I have another solution now …

Comment: The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches the URL-path only. "works fine but the GET-Parameters are empty" - Are you suggesting that even the hardcoded `ecSTAGE=query` parameter is omitted? "should work … shouldn’t it?" - But what are you expecting the `$1` backreference to contain (there are no capturing subpatterns)?